# How to convert a file to ogg audio only format?

Tags: ffmpeg, ogg, vorbis

I have used a few other examples i have found on this site but when i use them to convert say and mp3 or a flac file with embedded cover art, the resulting ogg file is treated more like a video file than an audio file by most music players. Namely VLC.

Here is the command i am using:

```
ffmpeg -i song.mp3 song.ogg
```

This works but seems to create a video file instead of an audio file. What i would like to do is either make it not include the album art from the source file **OR** have the correct ffmpeg command to properly add it to an ogg (audio only) file.

Answer (score 3):

Use this command :

```
ffmpeg -i video.any -vn -acodec libvorbis audio.ogg
```

Explanation:

- `-i` specifies the input file, which can be any kind of video file
- `-vn` means "no video", so extracting audio only
- `-acodec libvorbis` specifies encoding the audio as ogg.

More tips can be found at this
[ffmpeg gist](https://gist.github.com/protrolium/e0dbd4bb0f1a396fcb55).